# it seems no response when post request has been sent

Tags: jquery, ajax

Server has received the post request correctly and returns json data, but browser console doesn't display string "ok". How can I debug it?
HTML:

```
<form id="reg-form" method="post">
    <select id="year" name="1">
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
    </select> 

    <select id="month" name="2">
        <option value="3"></option>
        <option value="30"></option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="button" value="submit" id="post-btn"/>
</form>
```

Script:

```
$("#post-btn").click(function(){
    $.post("traffic", $("#reg-form").serialize(), function(json) {
        console.log("ok"); // question: "ok" doesn't show on console.
        $('#table2 tbody').empty();
        $('#tbody2').append("<tr></tr>");
        for (var i = 0; i <json.length; i++) {
            var result = json[i];
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change `input type="submit"` to `input type="button"` or change your code to:

```
$("#post-btn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of the code
```

Currently as you are not preventing the default behavior of `submit` button, after sending the post request browser must be submitting the form (refreshing the page). So your code is not getting executed.